# How to obtain Xml file path included in project, inside WebMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am making ajax call to a static WebMethod & need access to the web page path.. `Server.MapPath`.

But since instance variables are not accessible inside static method. We can't use Page properties inside `WebMethod.`

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetLogs()
{        
   //Can't use Server.MapPath("Resource.xml");
}
```

Also since this is a AJAX call, can't use other work arounds like storing `Server.MapPath` result in user defined property during Page_Load etc. is not going to work.

I see this is an inevitable problem, where sooner or later I will need access to page instance variables inside WebMethod, but can't access them during AJAX call.

What is the work around of the issue ?

Comment: Why is this a static method?

Comment: did you try using in `Application`. Like ` Application["ResourceUrl"]`.

Comment: @DavidKemp: methods in `ASPX` pages marked as `WebMethod` must be static (unlike `ASMX`)

Comment: @DavidKemp WebMethod has to be static, so that during ajax call we can make page/MethodName call directly.

Comment: @saravanan Application is also a property defined inside Page class !!

Comment: so why not use a asmx?

Comment: How about creating a static variable during application start and then use that within these static methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the static instance of Server.MapPath in this way:

```
using System.Web;
[WebMethod]
public static string GetLogs()
{        
    string resource = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Resource.xml");
}
```